# Listening comprehension (a war movie)

Tags: comprehension, listening

.    .
Hello, friends. Could anyone please listen to the [movie clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh8plaucbnU&t=2m50s)
(from 2m51s to 3m30s) 
and check my following transcription? for mistakes?

---

??? Go on! Don't get back here. No more. 
Why don't you close the entrance? Close the entrance. 
Filipino soldiers, Serge. They tried to get in. 
Chop(???) off those yellow monkeys. We can't afford to be suffocated here. 
Shoot them. Kill them. Shoot anything. Don't let them in. Monkeys! 
Yes, sir! All right, men. Get the machine gun ready. When I give the word, 
let them have it. (...) Let them have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go on!
Get back there.
Hey.
Hey.
No more.
No more.
Why don't you close the entrance?
Close the entrance.
Filipino soldiers sir, they're trying to get in.
Shut 'em off those yellow monkeys.
We can't afford to be suffocated here.
Shoot them.
Kill them.
Shoot anything. 
Don't let them in. 
Monkeys!
Yes, sir!
All right, men.
Get the machine gun ready.
When I give the word, let them have it.
Let 'em have it

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for your prompt and exhaustive answer. You've been a great help!