# Listening comprehension: a fighter anime

Tags: comprehension, listening

&
Hello, friends! (Not "fiends," mind you.)
I'm struggling to understand the first 30 seconds of this anime:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IGBVXLfmm8&t=10s

Could anyone please listen to its first portion and correct 
my dictation attempt shown below? Thank you very much for your time.

My attempt (from the 10-second to the 40-second point)

Hey! Fei Long! 
Uh, man, what's this?
Nothing. Looks like fun, that's all!
Fun?
Yeah! The dragons forced a schmuck into the ring. He was dumb enough to shoot off his big mouth, you know.
Hey, I didn't say anything.
Fighters don't take smart-ass remarks selectively(???) around here, chicken!
You can pack up your words, can't you?
Ahh, that's interesting! 
Maybe showbiz turned into big stuff.
But this stuff brings you back, doesn't it, huh?
Keep your eye on the new guy. He looks good!

Comment: It's not available in my country (USA). Also, we don't do proofreading or transcriptions. Maybe if you had a question about a particular word or sentence, it would be okay. But at the moment, it's also too broad.

Comment: Oh, so you don't proofreading or transcriptions? I thought you did, because some other members and I myself have posted similar requests before and people kindly responded. Here's one example:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109483/listening-comprehension-a-war-movie

Comment: Sometimes they're not closed--they slip by. I've answered some myself. But this one and that one are both too broad and should be closed, in my opinion.

Comment: I see. I understand. Thank you for your comment, Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original transcript, you have

> Hey! Fei Long! Uh, man, what's this? Nothing. **Looks like fun**, that's all! Fun? Yeah! **The dragons forced a** schmuck into the ring. **He was dumb** enough to shoot off his big mouth , you know. Hey, I didn't say anything. Fighters don't take smart-ass remarks **selectively** around here, chicken! You can **pack up** your words, can't you? Ahh, that's interesting! Maybe showbiz **turned into big stuff**. But this stuff brings you back, doesn't it, huh? Keep your eye on the new guy. He looks good!

The errors are listed here, maybe it will help your listening and understanding. Most seem to be due to not knowing what phrase is usually used in a circumstance, which will come with practice.

> **Looks like fun** -> A little extra fun
>   **The dragons forced a** -> They're dragging some poor
>   **He was dumb** -> And he was dumb
>   **selectively** -> lightly
>   **pack up** -> back up
>   **turned into big stuff** -> turned you into a big star

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your time, Peter. I've learned a great deal.

Comment: @OEDLovesMeNot Just remember to help someone else when you can and please mark the question as "answered" so other answerer won't stumble across it.

Comment: I think I've marked the question as "answered" now. I'm sorry I didn't know how to use the forum properly. And I greatly appreciate your valuable advice, Peter.